# Animate the height of a document jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to load a html document inside an expanding div and I want the to animate the expand.
As it is now i can only set a height and it animates that then just show the rest.

So i guess i want it to load the content and then animate it in, basically where it says 300px it should be the height of my html document (which is different since it's different project in my portfolio).

The box_project2 HTML is in the separate html document and should define the animated height.

Link to my site where you can see the acual problem by clicking on some of the top projects.
http://richardhedberg.com/portfolionew/index.html#

```
$('.thumbs2').click(function () {
    var idStr = ("project/" + $(this).attr('id'));
    var newHeight = 0;
    $('#show2').animate({ height: '300px', opacity: 0 }, function () {
        $('#workp').fadeIn('fast');
        $.scrollTo('#gohere', 300);

        $('#show2').load(idStr, function () {
            newHeight = $('#box_project2').outerHeight();
            $(this).animate({ height: newHeight }, 300, function () {
                $('#show2').delay(200).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 800);
                $('#close2').css({ 'display': 'block', 'height': '25px' });
            });
        });
    });
});




       <div id="close2">
       </div>  
       <div id="show2">
            <div id="box_project2">
            </div>
       </div>


.workp {
background:#fff;
position:relative;
z-index:999;
margin-bottom:30px;


}


#close2 {
position:absolute;
width:25px;
height:24px;
background:url(images/graphics/CloseIcon.png);
right:0px;
top:0px;
z-index: 9999;
display: none;
margin-left:-30px;



}
#show2 {
display: block;
height: 0px;
opacity: 1;
margin-left:-30px;
clear:both;

}

#box_project2 {

background:#fff;
text-align: left;
clear:both;
height:100%;


}
```

Comment: I think you're animating while it's opacity is 0. I don't totally follow but if you set up an example at jsfiddle.net it'll articulate your problem a lot better. :)

Comment: http://richardhedberg.com/portfolionew/index.html# if you want you can take a look at my site.

Answer (score 0):

And what's your question?

First you want to do the load and then the animation on load's callback?

But if you want to show to the user how much of the data has been loaded, then first you need to write your own animation class. Then on every frame you load the data and the on the callback you go to next frame. Note that you dynamically change url's in that case, because you don't have control over data flowing from one ajax call.

Comment: Actually, that load only executes when the animation is done. The callback function of `animate()` executes at the end of the animation, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Sorry pretty tired and probably unclear, what i want is to toggle my projects with an animated expanding div that loads at separate html file (ex. project1.html). So yes I guees i want to first load the document and then animate it in.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 $(this).animate({ height: newHeight }
```

should probably have the `px` unit appended and be

```
 $(this).animate({ height: newHeight + 'px' }
```

Comment: still just animates the 300px the $(this).animate({ height: newHeight } part does not animate at all.